# How to make autocompletion replace the entire line instead of the current keyword?

Tags: autocomplete, ace-editor

In Ace editor, I have a custom completer like this:

```
var customCompleter = {
  getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    callback(null, [
      { 
        value: 'foo.bar', score: 1, meta: 'History'
      }
    ])
  }
}
```

[image]

When I type `foo`, it suggests `foo.bar` and replace `foo` with `foo.bar`. But when I type `foo.b`, it replace `foo.b` with `foo.foo.bar` rather than `foo.bar`.

How can I make Ace autocompletion replace the entire line instead of current keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ace function **jumpToMatching** inside the **insertMatch** of your custom autocomplete to move to the cursor to the word's starting position and then use **replace** to add your autocompleted word.

```
var customCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        callback(null, [
            { 
                value: 'foo.bar', score: 1, meta: 'History',

                completer: {
                    insertMatch: function (insertEditor, data) {
                        var insertValue = data.value;
                        var lastPositon = editor.selection.getCursor();

                        insertEditor.jumpToMatching();
                        var startPosition = editor.selection.getCursor();

                        insertEditor.session.replace({
                            start: { row: startPosition.row, column: startPosition.column },
                            end: { row: lastPositon.row, column: lastPositon.column }
                        }, "");
                    }
                }
            ])
        }
    }
```

Here the **startPosition** would be where the word is starting and **lastPositon** is till where you would like the word to be replaced.